# Cocos 2D Large FPS Drop When Drawing Sprites

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, lag

I am drawing 52 labels, sprites, and buttons for a scroll view. However when i go to scroll it is very lagged when i use the scroll view. I use a similar setup that scrolls on the x and  axis that works with no lag. I am testing on an iphone 5 so i would think that it would be able to handle it very easily. The distance the the object need to move is being calculated correctly and the object are being draw correctly it is just really lagged. Draw code:

```
    int cnt = 40;      
  for (NSString *i in [Trucks GetSetTruckList].TruckList){
    NSMutableArray *Truck = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[TruckDict objectForKey:i]];
     CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];


    CCMenuItemImage *BuyButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"Buy.jpg" selectedImage:@"Buy.jpg"block:^(id sender) {[self BuyTruck:Truck]; }];
    BuyButton.position = ccp((s.width/2) - 20 , (s.height/2) - cnt  + ShopPointX);
    BuyButton.scale = .5;

    CCLabelTTF *Name = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[Truck objectAtIndex:0] fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:19];
    Name.position = ccp(100, (s.height) - cnt + ShopPointX);

    CCLabelTTF *NumPeople = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ppl: %@" , [Truck objectAtIndex:2]] fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:13];
    NumPeople.position = ccp(200, (s.height) - cnt + ShopPointX);

    CCLabelTTF *NumCrate = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Crgo: %@" , [Truck objectAtIndex:1]] fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:13];
    NumCrate.position = ccp(270, (s.height) - cnt + ShopPointX);

    CCSprite *Pic = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[Truck objectAtIndex:5]];
    Pic.position = ccp(340, (s.height) - cnt + ShopPointX);
    Pic.scale = .3;

    CCMenu *Menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:BuyButton, nil];
    cnt = cnt + 40;

    [self addChild:Pic];
    [self addChild:Menu];
    [self addChild:Name];
    [self addChild:NumCrate];
    [self addChild:NumPeople];
    StartShop = 1;
}
```

Comment: Im not using UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be having lag because OpenGL is making a separate draw call for each sprite. Are you putting sprites into a 'CCSpriteBatchNode'? It looks like all children are being added to 'self'. If you use batch nodes, OpenGL can make just one 'draw' call per CCSpriteBatchNode, no matter how many children are contained in the batch node. The only catch is that all CCSprites that are children of a CCSpriteBatchNode must share the same image.

One way to do it would be to put CCSpriteBatchNodes into an NSDictionary by image name, and also add each CCSpriteBatchNode to 'self'.

```
    // This line assumes usage of a CCSpriteFrameCache to init the sprite, but you can create it some other way.
    CCSprite *spr = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:spriteName];

    CCSpriteBatchNode *batchNode;
    if([self.batchNodeDictionary objectForKey: spriteName]) {
        // Acquire the batchnode by image name
        batchNode = (CCSpriteBatchNode *) [self.batchNodeDictionary objectForKey: spriteName];
    } else {
        // BatchNode for this image doesn't exist yet; therefore, populate a new batch node for the image name

        batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:spriteNamePNG];
        [self addChild:batchNode];
        [batchNodesDictionary setObject:batchNode forKey:spriteName];


    }
    [batchNode addChild:spr];
```

Comment: I've also read of 'preallocating' batch nodes with sprites, because the allocation and deallocation costs memory. So you could, for example, preallocate 1000 sprites, which would take more time, but then never have to allocate another sprite. You'd just set 'isVisible' to 'false' for the preallocated sprites that are not on screen. I haven't implemented this yet, but am planning on trying it in my own projects soon.

Comment: Hm i will look into batchNode, after looking at it a bit more i think that it is  problem with my code because with 30 sprites i stay to 60 fps.